# Create new texture from multitexture

Tags: opengl-es

I'm struggling trying to understand how to create a new texture (with a new GLHandle, if possible) after merging two other in the same concept of multitexturing. I'm doing this because I'm using ETC1 compressed textures, witch doesn't support alpha channel's, so I wanted to load the pre-generated alpha channel from another file and "merge" both of them after uncompressing.

I know that multitexturing does this, but it implies to render the two textures (compressed + alpha) altogether, right?

Also, I'm doing this because I've seen a massive speedup in my rendering pipeline by using compressed textures. If I recreate it with the alpha channel it's supposed that the performance benefits will stick, right?

Comment: Without rendering the two textures altogether (and therefore using multitexturing) you won't get them combined, as the textures are only uncompressed each time they are read for a specific fragment. So you cannot just uncompress the whole textures and merge them into one. You can do this, but you would just end up with a standard uncompressed texture, that would buy you nothing. Fragment shaders (przemo_li's answer) or fixed-function multitexturing (my answer) are the only ways to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with OpenGL ES 1.1 using multitexturing and the `GL_COMBINE` environment. First we use whatever standard environment you want for the color texture:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rgbTexture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);    //or maybe GL_REPLACE
```

Then for the alpha texture, which is bound to the second unit, we just take the color from the previous stage (the color texture) and only use the alpha of the texture.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, alphaTexture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTenEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);    //default
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_MODULATE);    //or maybe GL_REPLACE
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_ALPHA, GL_TEXTURE);     //default
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);  //default
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_ALPHA, GL_PREVIOUS);    //default
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);  //default
```

If I misunderstood you and you don't want to use multitexturing (and neither fragment shaders), then you won't be able to combine these two textures during rendering. Perhaps with a multipass technique but I'm not sure if that would buy you anything performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

**You just need fragment shader.**

In which you will mix color and alpha value from those two textures. Thats all. (Color goes as ususally, and alpha value go directly to output).

Comment: the fragment shader is only form OpenGLES 2.0 right? I'm unable to do this on 1.0?

Comment: Add info about OpenGL ES version to your question! Its important. And I can not help you cause do not know much about ES1.0/1.1